# WP Query - Posts repeated on different pages when using pagination and orderby => menu_order

Tags: wp-query

```
$q = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'post_type',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC'),
            'paged' => ((get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
        ]);
```

The above shows the same posts on each page.

If I remove the orderby arg, then it works (other than the desired ordering).

What am I doing wrong in the above snippet / why are the posts repeating on separate pages? Perhaps a bug in WP?

Comment: the code that implements your pagination is missing from your question so it isn't possible to check if `paged` is being set properly, can you edit your question to add it? Note that using `WP_Query` like this is usually a mistake, and the page could be many times faster if `pre_get_posts` was used to modify the main query, rather than throwing it away and paying the cost of a second query complete with all the technical debt of making things like pagination work again. Notice if your query has 5 pages, but the page it's on has 4, then page 5 will 404, even if your custom query has a 5th page!